# Is it possible and economic to structure data like this in redis?

Tags: caching, redis, bigdata

I have 2 objects - users and files.

Users can be admins or basic users. Files can be manually shared with users, admin users have view access to all files anyway.

I want to keep a cache of "what files can user x view" and "which users can view file x".

The problem is if user23 is an admin and you change that user to a basic user they will lose access to some files - but if the files have also been manually shared with user23 they should keep access.

So what about a structure like this:

```
user:23:files:admin => [1,2,3]
user:23:files:shared => [2]
file:1:users:admin => [23]
file:2:users:admin => [23]
file:3:users:admin => [23]
file:1:users:shared => []
file:2:users:shared => [23]
file:3:users:shared => []
```

So user:*userid*:files:*reason-why-user-can-view-files* and file:*fileid*:users:*reason-why-users-can-view-file*

So when the user has their admin access removed I would delete the `user:23:files:admin` key and update the 3 file keys to remove that user id.

I need to support hundreds of thousands of files so is there an efficient way to remove the user id from the files list in redis?

Or is there a better way to structure the data?

In my above example user23 would still have access to file2 as it has been manually shared with him. This would be the result:

```
user:23:files:admin => []
user:23:files:shared => [2]
file:1:users:admin => []
file:2:users:admin => []
file:3:users:admin => []
file:1:users:shared => []
file:2:users:shared => [23]
file:3:users:shared => []
```

Comment: I see one big problem with this approach: book-keeping. On every change you'll have to touch multiple keys. First (easy) question is: how do you accurately determine them? The hard part is how do you make sure that this behaves in a transactional manner (all operations succeed or none of them)?

Comment: A followup on the second question is: how do you know that your database is in a consistent state? Say, you revoke admin rights from a user, then go about deleting his file related keys, but your app crashes in the middle of the process. Now what?

Comment: I believe redis has the ability to open a transaction using EXEC. So if the DB transaction commits I then commit redis. Is the app crashes inbetween then they will be out of sync though.... am I trying to use redis when actually just using the DB might suffice?

Comment: Yes, I think that ACID database should be a safer choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you think querying your db is time consuming and you can handle those app server crashes (maintaining state) then use this solution.

Maintain a separate set for list of files

```
Sadd files 1 2
```

maintain a separate set for admin users

```
Sadd admin_users 1 2
```

a set for each file consisting of shared user id's

```
Sadd File:1 1 3
Sadd File:2 1 4
```

and a set for each user consisting of files shared to them.

```
Sadd User:1 1 2
Sadd User:3 1
Sadd User:4 2
```

Here the second user doesn't have an entry because no file is shared to him.

If a user requests for a file, if he is in the admin set allow or else look for the file set.

To show accessible files to a user show all the files if he is in the admin set or else take it from the user set.

If there is an update to a file, say it is shared to a new user or removed a user you need to handle them in user set and file set.

If someone is promoted as admin or removed handled it in admin set.

In this way you can achieve all the actions in 1 or 2 hits to redis.

Edit: regarding the memory perspective. Unless until a file is shared to a user there won't be entries in the set. In hundreds of thousands of files the number files which will be shared to more than 1000 users will be very minimal. Similarly an user to whom more than 1000 files shared will also be less.

So majority of the set you are going to use will take less memory. Only the set which stores all the file names will take more. Do a little test with for N number of users and m number of files.

Also you can use bit level operation for file sets and user sets. Use setbit operation and set the bits for each user ID in that file. This way you can reduce sets to a simple string. Which will reduce you some memory.